# unable to load kml file using geoxml3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gis, kml, geoxml3

i have tried to load two kml files, **[admin.kml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DkiSi2yKc-Z29HdFkyMG9xOHc/view?pli=1) and [pibkt.kml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DkiSi2yKc-cUIwVW1ja0FpYmM/view?pli=1)** , with the same code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps KML</title>
    <meta name="description" content="menampilkan polygon dari kml di googlemaps">
    <meta name="author" content="El Cicko">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var peta;
    function peta_awal(){
       // var jawa_barat = new google.maps.LatLng(0.89176, 123.38894);
        var petaoption = {
            zoom: 8,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        peta = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("petaku"),petaoption);

        var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: peta});

        geoXml.parse('admin.kml');
        google.maps.event.addListener(peta,'click',function(event){
            kasihtanda(event.latLng);
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="peta_awal()">
<h2>Google Maps KML</h2>
<div id="petaku" style="height:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when **i change  admin.kml to pibkt.kml**, my browser displays for nothing, i don't know why, because i can view both files online via  KML,KMZ viewer Google Drive
please help me, i'm totally new, i really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: What does the KML look like?

Comment: like https://goo.gl/ccmrMC (admin.kml) and  this https://goo.gl/AP6XQn (pibkt.kml)

Comment: I don't see any KML available at  [goo.gl/AP6XQn](https://goo.gl/AP6XQn) (pibkt.kml)

Comment: what? i just check it, but the green marker and also the polygons are stil there, on sulawesi island, you can download it  from https://goo.gl/qdLDwF

Comment: [That KML isn't valid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20150917_MyPlaces.kml).  I suspect the issue in geoxml3 is the `<Document>` tags inside the `<Folder>` tags.

Comment: can yoy give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey that is actually a bug from google earth pro. you can export your .kmz via my maps from google map

Answer (score 1):

[That KML isn't valid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20150917_MyPlaces.kml). I suspect the issue in geoxml3 is the  tags inside the  tags. If I replace the `<Document>` tags with `<Folder>` tags, it works for me:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20150917_MyPlacesNoDoc.kml

Comment: thank you, your answer is true, but i found another way also, and that was to **export my pibkt.kmz to pibkt.kml via My maps from google map**, because my previous pibkt.kml derived from Google Earth Pro, i think that's bug